# Apache Storm with Kafka offset management

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have built a sample topology with Storm using Kafka as a source. Here is a problem for which I need a solution.

Every time I kill a topology and start it again, the topology starts processing from the beginning.

Suppose Message A in Topic X was processed by Topology and then I kill the topology.

Now when I again submit the topology and Message A is still there is Topic X. It is processed again.

Is there a solution, maybe some sort of offset management to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `storm-kafka` for new code, it is deprecated since the underlying client API is deprecated in Kafka, and removed as of 2.0.0. Instead, use `storm-kafka-client`.

With `storm-kafka-client` you want to set a group id, and a first poll offset strategy.

```
KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, "your-topic")
            .setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "kafkaSpoutTestGroup")
            .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(UNCOMMITTED_EARLIEST)
            .build();
```

The above will make your spout start at the earliest offset first time you start it, and then it will pick up where it left off if you restart it. The group id is used by Kafka to recognize the spout when it restarts, so it can get the stored offset checkpoint back. Other offset strategies will behave differently, you can check the javadoc for the FirstPollOffsetStrategy enum.

The spout will checkpoint how far it got periodically, there is also a setting in the config to control this. The checkpointing is controlled by the `setProcessingGuarantee` setting in the config, and can be set to have at-least-once (only checkpoint acked offsets), at-most-once (checkpoint before spout emits the message), and "any times" (checkpoint periodically, ignoring acks).

Take a look at one of the example topologies included with Storm https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/dc56e32f3dcdd9396a827a85029d60ed97474786/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutTopologyMainNamedTopics.java#L93.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when creating your spoutconfig that it has a fixed spout id by which it can identify itself after a restart.

From official Storm site:

> Important: When re-deploying a topology make sure that the settings
>   for SpoutConfig.zkRoot and SpoutConfig.id were not modified, otherwise
>   the spout will not be able to read its previous consumer state
>   information (i.e. the offsets) from ZooKeeper -- which may lead to
>   unexpected behavior and/or to data loss, depending on your use case.

Comment: I assume the offsets are stored only for the acknowledged messages?

Comment: As @Stig said "The spout will checkpoint how far it got periodically, there is also a setting in the config to control this. The checkpointing is controlled by the setProcessingGuarantee setting in the config, and can be set to have at-least-once (only checkpoint acked offsets), at-most-once (checkpoint before spout emits the message), and "any times" (checkpoint periodically, ignoring acks"

Answer (score 0):

since I am facing with a similar issue, take advantage of it and ask. I have a code like this:

```
        KafkaTridentSpoutConfig.Builder kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder = KafkaTridentSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, topic);

    kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, fetchSizeBytes);
    kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
    kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    return new KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque(kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.build());
```

But everytime I restart Storm Local Cluster, messages are read from the beginning. If I check offsets directly in Kafka for the particular group, there is no lag. It's like offsets from Kafka are not read.
Using Kafka 2.8, Storm 2.2.0. I didn't have this issue with Storm 0.9.X.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30013590)